# UIBarButtonItem button not firing

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I have an app with a UINavigationController with a bunch of UITableViewControllers that I swap out based on what the user selects. All of the UITableViewControllers have a button "Add Event". On about half of the table view controllers, the button won't fire at all. For the life of me, I can't figure out why.

Here's an example of an init function of one that DOESN't work. The button in question is the "doneButton". It is not firing addEvent() when clicked.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle: UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    if (self) {
        // initialize toolbar
        toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( 0, 0, 768, 44 )];
        titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( 284, 4, 200, 35 )];
        titleLabel.text = @"End Repeat";
        titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 20];
        titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [toolbar addSubview: titleLabel];
        UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target: nil action: nil];
        UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Add Event" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target: self action: @selector(addEvent)];
        NSArray *buttonArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: flexibleSpace, doneButton, nil];
        [toolbar setItems: buttonArray];
        [self.view addSubview: toolbar];

        // initialize date picker
        datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( 0.0, 0.0, 768.0, 216.0 )];
        datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
        [datePicker addTarget: self action: @selector(changeDate) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];

        [self roundDatePicker];
        [self parseDone];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Here's an example of an init function of one that DOES work:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle: UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        caController = [[CAViewController alloc] init];
        selectedRow = 0;

        self.title = @"Calendar";

        self.toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( 0, 0, 768, 44 )];
        titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( 284, 4, 200, 35 )];
        titleLabel.text = @"Select Calendar";
        titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 20];
        titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [toolbar addSubview: titleLabel];
        UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target: nil action: nil];
        UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Add Event" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target: self action: @selector(addEvent)];
        NSArray *buttonArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: flexibleSpace, doneButton, nil];
        [toolbar setItems: buttonArray];
        [self.view addSubview: toolbar];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: -(IBAction)addEvent:(id)sender should be the method, change your selector as @selector(addEvent:)

Comment: Post your code for addEvent in the class thet doesn't work.

Comment: I tried changing to `-(IBAction)addEvent:(id)sender` with no success. My code for addEvent shouldn't matter because I'm just putting a break point there, but here it is:

Comment: `- (IBAction) addEvent: (id) sender
{
 //[self parseDone];
    
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 UINavigationController *controller = (UINavigationController *)[delegate.splitController.viewControllers objectAtIndex: 0];
 RootTableViewController *rootController = (RootTableViewController *)[controller.viewControllers objectAtIndex: 0];
    
    [rootController parseDone];
}`

Comment: I also tried adding a different method to the action of the done button. It still won't fire. It's as if there is something invisible covering the button so that I cannot click on it.

Answer (score 1):

2 months of rebuilding my app step-by-step and I finally found it! This was blocking my button:

```
- (UIView*) tableView: (UITableView*) tableView viewForHeaderInSection: (NSInteger) section {
    return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 1)];
}
```

For the life of me I can't figure out what this code does or why I even put it in there in the first place. I deleted it and now everything seems to be working fine.